# Prevent Api from being called from UI with ESLint?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, eslint

In our product, we have an Api, that delivers a huge response. Which is most likely no problem, when we call it from a CLI, but calling it from a browser via XmlHttpRequest kills the browser.

**My question**

Is there a way, to check for specific string occurences? I have no idea, how to check otherwise, but the Api route.

Let's say the route is `/api/hugeResponse`. If one of my teammate is writing something like this:

```
 1. class ApiService {
 2.   
 3.   constructor($http) {
 4.     this.$http = $http;
 5.   }
 6. 
 7.   hugeReponseApi() {
 8.     const request = {
 9.      method: "GET",
10.      url: "api/hugeResponse"
11.     };
12.
13.     return this.$http(request);
14.   }
15.
16. }
```

I want the linter to throw an error on line 10.

Comment: Try [Angular Interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors).  You may also want to look into WebWorkers.  Maybe you can get away with doing your fetching in a worker thread, processing it, and then bringing it to the main thread without killing the browser.

Comment: What is the goal?  To prevent developers from calling this API?

Comment: A linter is only a heuristic, it cannot catch all cases. Surely you can make it balk on object literals that contain an `url` property with the offending string value.

Comment: Other ideas: put the huge response api on the blacklist of your favourite addblocker in the development test browser. Or check the useragent header in the API and return an error message "this result is too big for a browser" instead of the response. Both should cause errors that can be caught in your tests.

Comment: Linter will not save you from `url: ApiBaseUrl + "/hugeResponse"` I believe. You should reconsider your options, some which are: a) client side caching; b) user-agent, or custom header-based API responses (say 403 Forbidden might be an option); c) maybe optimize the API itself; d) maybe use pagination in the API; etc. As @zero298 is right. If a developer is determined, she'll make the API call no matter how you set up your linter...

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko and Bergi I like your approach of checking the user agent. Of course this could be modified from the UI, but this has to be done very conscious. So, I will give this a try. Thanks!

Comment: @zero298 exactly. Better to say, preventing the developers from calling the Api from the UI. Calling it from a shell is fine. Otherwise I would not define this Api as public.